# Generating a Selenium Report with Allure

Tags: selenium, homebrew, allure

I want to get the report of my Selenium Junit Test using Allure. I installed Allure via Homebrew and my version is 1.4.23.

Below is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>



    <properties>
        <selenium.version>3.14.0</selenium.version>
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.3.1</junit.jupiter.version>
        <junit.vintage.version>5.3.1</junit.vintage.version>
        <junit.platform.version>1.3.1</junit.platform.version>
        <allure-maven.version>2.8</allure-maven.version>
        <allure-junit5.version>2.7.0</allure-junit5.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.19.1</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.7.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.9.1</aspectj.version>

        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.encoding>UTF-8</project.encoding>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>${project.encoding}</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>${project.encoding}</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!--Selenium Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--JUNIT 5 Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.vintage.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Allure Reporting Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>${allure-junit5.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>listener</name>
                            <value>io.qameta.allure.junit5.AllureJunit5</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                    </argLine>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <property>
                            <name>allure.results.directory</name>
                            <value>${project.basedir}/allure-results</value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                            <name>junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled</name>
                            <value>true</value>
                        </property>
                    </systemProperties>
                    <reportFormat>plain</reportFormat>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>5.1.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                <version>${allure-maven.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And Here is the LogintestTest.java

```
package com.example.demo;

// Generated by Selenium IDE
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.After;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsNot.not;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import io.qameta.allure.Epic;
import io.qameta.allure.Feature;

import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

@Epic("Login Tests Epic")
@Feature("Invalid Login Features")
//@SpringBootTest
public class LogintestTest extends WatchManClassConsole{
    private WebDriver driver;
    private Map<String, Object> vars;
    JavascriptExecutor js;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/imseongbeen/Downloads/chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        vars = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void logintest() {
        driver.get("http://secure.smartbearsoftware.com/samples/testcomplete12/WebOrders/login.aspx");
        driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1440, 877));
        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_MainContent_username")).sendKeys("Tester");
        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_MainContent_password")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_MainContent_password")).sendKeys("test");
        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_MainContent_login_button")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_logout")).click();
    }
}
```

I get these errors when I write this command in terminal.

```
$allure generate directory-with-results/
Exception in thread "main" ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.ReportGenerationException: Could not find any allure results
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.AllureReportGenerator.generate(AllureReportGenerator.java:58)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.AllureReportGenerator.generate(AllureReportGenerator.java:53)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.AllureMain.main(AllureMain.java:48)
Command aborted due to exception {}.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:153)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.command.ReportGenerate.runUnsafe(ReportGenerate.java:48)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.command.AbstractCommand.run(AbstractCommand.java:52)
    at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.CommandLine.main(CommandLine.java:46)
```

I don't know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

From pom.xml I see

```
<property>
  <name>allure.results.directory</name>
  <value>${project.basedir}/allure-results</value>
</property>
```

The directory where the results are stored is "allure-results" under your project.

So the command to generate allure report should be:

```
allure generate allure-results
```

Comment: Thank you. I made the directory 'allure-results' under my project but the exception still happens, same as before. Is it because allure-report/data folder is empty?